# Custom Facebook Pages not viewable (blank page) for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/create-custom-facebook-pages/17957) to create a custom page on some facebook pages; now the problem is that some people can't see anything: they can see only a blank page inside facebook

The pages are:

https://www.facebook.com/AmbassadorRicevimenti (clicking on Home tab some people can't see my html page)

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Le-torte-di-Antonietta/173602889364785 (clicking on Home tab some people can't see my html page)

For these pages I've got both https and http urls; I've even tried to put only "hello word" in these pages, but nothing, some people can't see anything.

Obviously sandbox mode is off, so everyone can see the page.

I've seen that this blank page happens both with facebook logged users, and with not logged users (so people that tries to see the page without logging on facebook, but using a direct link); many other people (logged and not) can see the page without problems.

Comment: Works for me in the USA on Win7 with FF / Chrome / IE9. Looks like you need to dig deeper with the users who have a problem and find out what browser, os, isp, etc. they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like the Secure Page Tab URLs for your Tab Application are working fine, but your Page Tab URLs are not.  For both of the Facebook pages you shared, I can see your App content if I'm browsing over https but not for http.  On both pages I see the error message "Loggati su Facebook per vedere questa pagina. Grazie mille," when viewing the Tab over http. (This translates to "Log into Facebook" in Italian, but I am logged in.)

Are your sure the http URL is working properly?

Do you have any App settings or features in your http URL that would break the page when it is viewed over http instead of https?

Comment: some people told me that they see a 404 page in facebook iframe, so I wrote that message... I've checked http url and it works fine: http://www.brucisystems.com/facebook/ambassador/index.html

Comment: so, I've tried disabling ssl connection in facebook, and I got that message I wrote (please login on facebook): it seems that normal url doesn't work, but I can see in the browser when I type it directly!! I can't understand...

Comment: And you're sure there's no typo in the Page Tab URL in your app settings?  (And the Page Tab URL is listed as http, not https?)

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't know why, but the problem was exactly this described by you (but no typo in url). How I've solved this issue? I've deleted page tab in the app, and then I've redone all the steps: now it works well!

Comment: Awesome!  I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be related to your server sending the HTTP Header `X-Frame-Options`, that when set to `DENY` forbids browsers to iframe the served document.

There is an option `ALLOW facebook.com` (or other domain), but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) is not well supported yet.

Some browsers ignoring this setting would explain the behaviour you see.